# PHP: json_decode

Tags: php, json

I have to parse values from a json string like this:

```
[{"type":"list","value":["A","B"],"field":"scheda"}]
```

How can I do that using PHP function `json_decode`?

For example I want print:

```
field = "scheda"
values = "A,B"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$json = json_decode('[{"type":"list","value":["A","B"],"field":"scheda"}]');
print 'field = "'.$json[0]->field.'"'."\n";
print 'values = "'.implode(",",$json[0]->value).'"'."\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use `json_decode()`, why not try a class?

For instance, something like... http://www.phpclasses.org/package/4205-PHP-Serialize-and-unserialize-values-in-JSON-format.html